# Admin Title not showing up after being dynamically added

Tags: piranha-cms

I'm creating a new Piranha CMS application from scratch and I'm extending the administrative section to add another tab to the Content section. I'm adding this to the menu dynamically like this:

```
// create the product submenu item in Content master menu
        Manager.Menu.Where(m => m.InternalId == "Content").Single().Items.Add(
              new Manager.MenuItem()
              {
                  InternalId = "Product",
                  Name = "Product",
                  Action = "Index",
                  Controller = "ProductAdmin",
                  Permission = "ADMIN",
                  SelectedActions = "Index, Edit, Create"
              });
```

What other working admin menus the HTML look like is this

```
<div class="title">
<div class="container_12">
<div class="grid_12">
<h1>Pages</h1>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

When I add this line to my View:

```
@Html.Partial("Partial/Tabs")
```

It generates this HTML (with H1 missing):

```
<div class="title">
<div class="container_12">
<div class="grid_12">
<h1></h1>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

How do I get that H1 populated when adding tab dynamically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **H1** is not populated by the menu object. The simple reason for this is that you might want to have the titles:

- Products
- Add new product
- Edit product

for different views that are all related to that one menu item. The H1 is populated by setting `ViewBag.Title` either in your views or in your controller actions.

Regards

Håkan

Comment: This solution worked like a charm. Thank you Hakan. Wonderful product!